# How to make a function stop ignoring functions called within it Python

Tags: python

I have a function which reads the keyboard, and according to input is supposed to print a specific message, but it keeps ignoring it and printing just the control numbers:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from stickDerecho45Video import display
import time


mutex = Lock()
videomax = 1


def escribirValor(sacagawea):
    global videomax
    with mutex:
        videomax = sacagawea

def frustracion():
    print("1")
    escribirValor(1)


def reflexivo():
    print("2")
    escribirValor(2)



def confusion():
    print("3")
    escribirValor(3)



def masVerguenza():
    print("4")
    escribirValor(4)



def Input():
    while True:
        print("wait for key input")
        with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
                '<left>+<up>': frustracion,
                '<right>+<up>': reflexivo,
                '<right>+<down>': confusion,
                '<left>+<down>': masVerguenza})as h:
            h.join()
        display(videomax)
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

The funciton it is supposed to call is this one:

from subprocess import run
#from stickDerecho45Input import leerValor #,leerNombre
import time

```
def display(x):

    if x == 1:
        print("frustracion")
        #time.sleep(0.25)
    
if x == 2:
    print("reflexivo")
    #time.sleep(0.25)

if x == 3:
    print("confusion")
    #time.sleep(0.25)

if x == 4:
    print("masVerguenza")
    #time.sleep(0.25)

if x == 5:
    print("finito")
```

A trial input is by pressing any random combination of the four declared in hotkeys, the output has been a list of numbers
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
4
which I use to know if the hotkey functions were called. depending on input, but never the intended display.

the ideal output would be= frustracion frustracion reflexivo confusion.

I am using Pynput module to monitor the keyboard.

Comment: You have several indentation problems in this code. I can't tell which of them are incidental and which might be causing the problem you're asking about. As given, your code would error out if someone attempted to run it.

Comment: the indentation problems are because when i did the copy-paste of the code, the page didn't recognize it as code, had to do some formating corrections, this isn't the actual indentation, the code itself runs without marking any error.

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question and fix it. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368) to make sure you know how to format code without messing up indentation.

Comment: In most cases the highest chance to get a good answer is to provide a fully reproducable example, which means, prvoding code, some (ideally short) input, the output, that you get and the output, that you would like to get.
If others can copy / paste your code, run your example input, see that they get the same output as you (no error during copy paste) and can try some fixes until they get the right output then you get answers much faster.

Comment: I have made the corrections to the format. including desired input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the PYNPUT hotkey class is terribly invasive, so even in separate threads, it does not recognize anything it doesn't call. The solution has been to place the calls to display inside the functions assigned to hotkeys.

After heavy modification, here is the code:

Input script:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from stickDerecho45Video import display
import time


def frustracion():
    display(1)

def reflexivo():
    display(2)

def confusion():
    display(3)

def masVerguenza():
    display(4)

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<left>+<up>': frustracion,
        '<right>+<up>': reflexivo,
        '<right>+<down>': confusion,
        '<left>+<down>': masVerguenza})as h:
    h.join()

def Despliegue():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Display script:

```
import time

def display(x):

    if x == 1:
        print("frustracion")
        time.sleep(0.25)
    
    if x == 2:
        print("reflexivo")
        time.sleep(0.25)

    if x == 3:
        print("confusion")
        time.sleep(0.25)
    
    if x == 4:
        print("masVerguenza")
        time.sleep(0.25)

    if x == 5:
        print("finito")
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

One very obvious error is, that `escribirValor()` is assigning the paramer's value to a **local** variable named `videomax`

There might be other issues, but this is definitely something you have to fix.

It should assign to the global variable with that name:

so

```
def escribirValor(sacagawea):
    global videomax
    with mutex:
        videomax = sacagawea
```

**Addendum after first feedback:**
I do not know your keyboard module, but ther might be an indentation issue.

Can you tell us what output you get with following modifications to your code:

```
def Input():
    while True:
        print("wait for key input")
        with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
                '<left>+<up>': frustracion,
                '<right>+<up>': reflexivo,
                '<right>+<down>': confusion,
                '<left>+<down>': masVerguenza})as h:
            h.join()
            print("joined")
        print("after with statement")
    
        display(videomax)
        print("display called")
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: I made this correction and it did made it possible for videomax to change value, but the function call is somehow still unrecognized.

Comment: Ideally you show us some short input, the output, that you get and the output, that you want to get.
This should make it easier to help you identifying the issue.

Comment: It seems like it still doesn't call it, this is the output, trying randomly:
wait for key input
1
3
1
3

Comment: It seems you don't reach the `print("joined")` statement  and thus none of the lines afterwards. I assume, that `keyboard.GlobalHotKeys()` executes an infinite loop calling the callbacks for your keys
You might want to run a loop calling  the `display()` function and a `sleep`  in a separate thread . 

As I said before showing us what you expect (I suggest you enhance and edit your question) might help. most people will probably only look at the question (and perhaps the comments on your question) and not look here.

Describing in a few words what you try to achieve might help as well